# How to use regular expression in Email Text Field for rahul.123@clicksabcd.com?

Tags: regex, swift, email-validation

I am using this code to validate the email text field.

```
static func validateEmail(candidate: String) -> Bool {
        let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._]+@[A-Za-z]+.[A-Za-z]{1,35}"
        return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluate(with: candidate)
    }
```

But when i type "rahul.123@clicksabcd.com", then the app will freeze. I don't know how to use regular expression in iOS.

Comment: should use this regex - `"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"`. 

For detail & proper function, i have added the answer , check it.

Comment: have you solved your problem

Comment: yes............

Answer (score 0):

Use this class method for Email Validation...

```
 class func isValidEmail(_ strEmail:String) -> Bool {

    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    if(!strEmail.isEmpty){
        if(strEmail[strEmail.startIndex] == "."){

            return false
        }else{

            let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
            return emailTest.evaluate(with: strEmail)
        }
    }else{
        return false
    }
}
```

you can use this method as

```
ValidationClass.isValidEmail(userEmail!)
```

Thanks...

Comment: characters is deprecated. You shouldn't use count property to check if a collection is empty

Comment: `let index = strEmail.index(strEmail.startIndex, offsetBy: 0)` is pointless. Why not simply `strEmail.startIndex` or even better `strEmail.first == "."`

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus I have updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.0**

You can write email validate function in `String` `extension` as like below.

```
extension String {

   func isValidEmail() -> Bool {
       let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", options: [.caseInsensitive])

       return regex?.firstMatch(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, self.count)) != nil
    } 
}
```

and you can use it as like below.

```
var email = "mrvora@gmail.com"

if email.isValidEmail() {
   //correct email
}
```

Comment: characters is deprecated

Comment: `NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions` default value is an empty array  `[]`. you can just omit the options

Comment: When creating a NSRange you should use String utf16 count (probably not an issue when using it against an email string but you should get used to it)

Comment: String has no length property

Comment: Btw using do try catch and not printing the error is pointless. just use try?

Comment: one liner `return (try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", options: [.caseInsensitive]))?.firstMatch(in: self, range: NSMakeRange(0, utf16.count)) != nil`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..!

```
 extension String {
    func isEmail() -> Bool {
         let expression = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", options: [.caseInsensitive])

        return expression.firstMatch(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, characters.count)) != nil
     }
 }
```

Tested in Playground:

```
var str = "rahul.123@clicksabcd.com"
var str2 = "rahul.123@clicksabcd32com"

str.isEmail()  //true
str2.isEmail() //false
```